# c++ how to assign specific value to defining class in another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I try to pass some int value to constructor of class in another class. 
example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( int k );
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    A a(1);    //this show me "error: expected identifier before numeric constant"
};
```

Is there a way to do this? Or this is insane from my site?

Comment: Could you show your `class A` definition

Comment: @FirstStep It's actually shown, but OP stupidly refuses my edits. Well, the declaration is shown, but definition doesn't play a primary role in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Sure, the correct way to do this is to use the member initialzer list from class `B`:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : a(1) {}
    A a;
};
```

> or this is insane from my site?

No, nothing insane. Just straight forward using the correct syntax.

---

Another way may be to provide a default constructor for class `A`

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A( int k );
};
```

and do the initialization inside `B`'s constructor body:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() {
        a = A(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: There isn't one "correct" way anymore. `A a{1}; ` would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

A member can only be initialized in-class using a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. Both of the following would be grammatically correct:

```
A a{1};
A a = A(1);
```

In fact, if `A::A(int)` isn't explicit, then you could also do simply

```
A a = 1;
```